# Eel urllib request function returns null to JS, but value to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, eel

I have the following Python code for Eel

```
import eel, urllib.request

@eel.expose
def python_function():
    response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com').read()
    return(response)

eel.init('web')
eel.start('index.html', port=0)
```

Now when I call this from JavaScript with

```
async function jsFunction() {
    let result = await eel.python_function()();

    return result;
}
```

I always get `null`. When I call `print(python_function())` from Python I get an HTML string as expected.

When testing, JavaScript returns null before the URL is reached. I thought Python blocked code. Do I need to reimplement a block? Returning a string from `python_function` will get the actual string in the `jsFunction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@eel.expose
def python_function():
    response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com').read()

    return response.decode('latin1')
```

The difference is the `response.decode('latin1')` return.

In the Python layer of Eel, you must return an object that is serializable according  to the [Python's JSON encoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), and the raw binary string returned by `read()` is not serializable.

Take a look at the answer I provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824339/eel-function-returns-null/68825817#68825817) for a detailed explanation of the communication requirements between the Python and JavaScript layers of Eel.

Also, a separate issue that you should address in your Python code is that `eel.init('web')` should appear *before* any `@eel.expose`. As it is currently written, you're probably seeing an error being displayed in the JavaScript console about not being able to load some resources.